# UIView doesnot update after changing other UIViews which constraint it

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, constraints

[image]

I have a UIView contains two Labels as above. The initial width of Label is, say, 150px. And I set its text to "LabelA" and run sizeToFit(), and its width becomes 80px. I think since I have set the constraint for Label B which should have a 2px leading space to Label A, **now Label A is smaller, so Label B should move left**. But nothing happened! Why?

I used breakpoints and find that Label A's width had changed. But in Reveal, Label A's width remained.

Comment: Try to call `lbB.layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: @anhtu Thanks but this doesn't work...

Comment: You need to call `setNeedsLayout` on parent view of these `UILabels`.

Comment: How about try with the parent of lbA and lbB.

Comment: Reveal shows Label A's width has not changed. Why?